# Sending an SMS message using zenoss and python

Tags: python, performance, design-patterns

I have just finished a simple python script which uses [**this module**](https://github.com/iamseth/python-zenoss) to call **[Zenoss](http://wiki.zenoss.org/Main_Page)** API for getting live events. What the script does:

- connects to zenoss
- reads a file which has one phone number on each line
- sends a message to each number by `POST`ing some data(first of all it authenticates) to a specific URL with the following parameters: `phonenr`, `smstxt`, `Submit`

The script speaks for itself and it doesn't need comments. What I'm looking for is some logic in the script / cases that I didn't covered / coding standards that are wrong / design patterns and maybe some advices on how I can improve the code ( in a way that will make each number receive the message at the same time - maybe using multithreading will help )

The file that contains the phone numbers looks like this:

```
phone_no1
phone_no2
..
phone_non
```

The code is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-

import urllib2 as urllib
from urllib import urlencode
from os.path import join as joinPath
from traceback import print_tb
from os.path import isfile
from sys import exc_info

import myzenoss

zenoss = myzenoss.Zenoss('ip_of_zenoss', 'admin', 'pass')
hdrs = {'User-Agent': "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686) Gecko/20071127 Firefox/2.0.0.11"}
gh_url = 'http://ip-for-post/txsms.cgi'  # basically this is an IP for a Mobilink which sends the SMS

APPLICATION_PATH = '/srv/sms_alert/'
ALERT_POINT_PATH = joinPath(APPLICATION_PATH, 'alert_contact')

try:
    isInProduction = False
    for evt in zenoss.get_events():
        if evt['prodState'] == 'Production':
            isInProduction = True

            if isInProduction and isfile(ALERT_POINT_PATH):
                alertContactContent = None
                with open(ALERT_POINT_PATH, 'r') as alertContactFile:
                    alertContactContent = alertContactFile.read()
                alertContactContent = alertContactContent.splitlines()

                if alertContactContent:
                    evt['summary'] = ':zenoss]\n\nError: {0}'.format(evt['summary'])
                    evt['device']['text'] = '{0}'.format(evt['device']['text'])

                    final_message = '{0}\nName: {1}\n\n'.format(evt['summary'], evt['device']['text'])

                    for alertContactContentLine in alertContactContent:
                        data = {'phonenr': alertContactContentLine, 'smstxt': str(final_message), 'Submit': 'SendSms'}
                        data = urlencode(data)

                        req = urllib.Request(gh_url, data, headers=hdrs)
                        password_manager = urllib.HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm()
                        password_manager.add_password(None, gh_url, 'admin', 'password')

                        auth_manager = urllib.HTTPBasicAuthHandler(password_manager)
                        opener = urllib.build_opener(auth_manager)

                        urllib.install_opener(opener)
                        handler = urllib.urlopen(req)
                break  # used this to only get the last event
            else:
                evt['summary'] = '#[ERROR: SMS ALERT NO CONTACT]# {0}'.format(evt['summary'])

except Exception as e:
    ex_type, ex, tb = exc_info()
    print('\n #[ERROR]#  TRANSFORM: exception: {ex}\n'.format(ex=e))
    print('\n #[ERROR]#  TRANSFORM: exception traceback: {trace}\n'.format(trace=print_tb(tb)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using 'guard clauses'.
Currently you have a large amount of indents that could be removed with these.
Take:

> ```
> if isInProduction and isfile(ALERT_POINT_PATH):
>     alertContactContent = None
>     with open(ALERT_POINT_PATH, 'r') as alertContactFile:
>         alertContactContent = alertContactFile.read()
>     alertContactContent = alertContactContent.splitlines()
> ```

This could be:

```
if not (isInProduction and isfile(ALERT_POINT_PATH)):
    continue

alertContactContent = None
with open(ALERT_POINT_PATH, 'r') as alertContactFile:
    alertContactContent = alertContactFile.read()
alertContactContent = alertContactContent.splitlines()
```

The latter is much easier to read.
And even easier to read with multiple of these statements.

---

I'd also, like [`urllib2`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html), recommend the [Requests package](http://requests.readthedocs.org/en/master/).

> **See also:** The [Requests package](http://requests.readthedocs.org/en/master/) is recommended for a higher-level http client interface.

---

I'd recommend not checking if `ALERT_POINT_PATH` is a file and just try and open it.
This will prevent a [TOCTOU bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/404795/lbyl-vs-eafp-in-java/405220#405220).

To do this you can change:

```
if isInProduction and isfile(ALERT_POINT_PATH):
    alertContactContent = None
    with open(ALERT_POINT_PATH, 'r') as alertContactFile:
        alertContactContent = alertContactFile.read()
    alertContactContent = alertContactContent.splitlines()

    ...
else:
    evt['summary'] = '#[ERROR: SMS ALERT NO CONTACT]# {0}'.format(evt['summary'])
```

Into:

```
try:
    with open(ALERT_POINT_PATH, 'r') as f:
        alert_contact_content = f.readlines()
except IOError:
    evt['summary'] = '#[ERROR: SMS ALERT NO CONTACT]# {0}'.format(evt['summary'])
    continue
```

This significantly reduces the complexity of the algorithm.

This uses a correct `try` `except` where you specify the error.
And instead uses `f.readlines()` rather then `alertContactFile.read().splitlines()`.

---

I'd recommend joining your formats into one line:

```
final_message = ':zenoss]\n\nError: {0}\nName: {1}\n\n'.format(evt['summary'], evt['device']['text'])
```

And using a comprehension to pre-filter all the non `evt['prodState'] == 'Production'` evts.

---

In short I'd recommend:

```
def send_error_messages(zenoss):
    for evt in (e for e in zenoss.get_events() if e['prodState'] == 'Production'):
        try:
            with open(ALERT_POINT_PATH, 'r') as f:
                alert_contact_content = f.readlines()
        except IOError:
            evt['summary'] = '#[ERROR: SMS ALERT NO CONTACT]# {0}'.format(evt['summary'])
            continue

        if not alert_contact_content:
            continue

        final_message = ':zenoss]\n\nError: {0}\nName: {1}\n\n'.format(evt['summary'], evt['device']['text'])
        for phone_address in alert_contact_content:
            send_message({'phonenr': phone_address, 'smstxt': final_message, 'Submit': 'SendSms'})
        break
```

Where `send_message` is your `urllib2` functions.

Answer (score 1):

- The one coding standard is
  [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) and indeed it would
  be good if at least names are in common Python spelling, not like
  Java.  E.g. it should be `join_path` (if you really want to rename
  it), not `joinPath`, etc.
- The names vs. positional arguments for `format` are a bit
  inconsistent; I'd say that unless you have a lot of arguments you can
  usually get by with unnamed positional instead, i.e.
  `"{} {}".format(...)`.
- I don't like the tendency for stripping out characters in names
  unnecessarily:  `hdrs` and `evt` aren't exactly much saving compared
  to `headers` and `event`.
- The import for `os.path` is mentioned twice, that could also be just
  one line instead.
- `'{0}'.format(...)` should probably be `str(...)` if you need the
  string conversion.

Now for the structure I see a couple of things.

- The `try`/`catch` block looks like it's not very much improving on
  what the Python interpreter would print by default.
- "Declaring" the `isInProduction` variable is not needed and
  considering it's set to `True` immediately it looks like it's not
  needed at all.  Or the indentation is wrong, in which case it should
  instead be immediately initialised like
  `is_in_production = event['prodState'] == 'Production'`.
- Actually, initialising variables this way like again with
  `alertContactContent` is just not useful in Python.  I'd likely move
  reading the file and splitting the content into a function and use
  that instead (like
  `alert_contact_content = read_and_split(ALERT_POINT_PATH)` or so).
- Again, the body of the innermost `for`-loop looks like it should be a
  function instead, like `create_auth_manager()` and should only be
  created once - unless I'm missing something all of those
  `password_manager` instances are the same, so it makes sense to reuse
  them instead.
- I don't understand the `break`.  Or the comment on it.  At all.

Basically reading all of this nested stuff would be much easier if it
was *structured*, e.g. using functions or so.